# JOIN with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to get a list of singers that have at least 1 song on their albums:

```
CREATE TABLES singers
id_singer
name_singer
```

We list songs with their singers:

```
CREATE TABLE songs
id_song
id_singers // this is the id_singer in singers table
```

This table is used in case we have a same song for 2 or more singers

```
CREATE TABLE songs_join
id_sj
id_song_join // this is the id_song on songs table
id_singer_join // this is the id_singer in singers tables
```

So we need to look for a singer that his id exists in the songs list (`singer.id_singer` = `songs_id_singers`) and the `songs.id_song` should be equal to `songs_join.id_song_join` in one query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share any code you have tried

Comment: It has no sense to have the singer id in songs table. I think you should use only the join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.

`SELECT name_singer
FROM singers
INNER JOIN songs ON songs.id_singers = singers.id_singer
INNER JOIN songs_join ON songs_join.id_singer_join = singers.id_singer;`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT * FROM singers AS s
JOIN songs AS so ON so.id_signer = s.id_singer
JOIN songs_join AS sj ON sj.id_signer_join = s.id_singer
     AND sj.id_song_join = so.id_song
```

Comment: nice one, but quite complicated